# how is a country defined by its latutue and longitude

Tags: web-services

I am designing a database to store details of a hotel, where i have to classify according to country, state, city, region and its all defined separately as tables. The hotel tables have a foreign key for them and hotel's latitude and longitude.

But i have to define each country,state,city,region with its latitude and longitude too. A simple MIN Latitude/longitude and MAX latitude/longitude isnt enough as some cities may be round or it may not be possible that way without significant error.

How do i define the global position of the city. I have to have a reasonable error rate (say 20%).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the concept you are looking for is the [centroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid). Calculating these on your own would be quite difficult. You should probably use a geocoding api like the one provided by [google](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/).